# ArgumentError calling a Proc

Tags: ruby, proc-object

```
s = Proc.new {|x|x*2}
puts s.call(5)
-> 10

def foo(&a)
 a.call(5)
end

puts "test foo:"
foo(s)
```

When I try to call the proc above, I get:

```
foo: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

My expectation was that I can pass a proc to a method if the method is defined with this type of signature:

```
def foo(&a)
```

and then I can execute the proc insiide foo like this:

```
 a.call(5)
```

Comment: With "def foo(&a)" you can also "yield(5)" to the block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to pass an actual proc to foo, just define it with `def foo(a)`. Putting the `&` in front of `a` means "this isn't actually an argument. Instead take the *block* passed to this method, create a proc out of it, and store that proc in the variable a". In other words with your current definition you can call foo like this:

```
foo do |x|
  puts x*2
end
```

You can also use `&` when calling a method to turn a proc into a block:

```
foo(&s)
```